# Handle UI in all iPhones with different scaling/resolutions

Tags: ios, screen, iphone-6

What is the best approach to handle iPhone4, iPhone5, iPhone6, iPhone6+ UI Screens in iOS?

- Size for iPhone 6+ with @3x scaling, Coordinate space: 414 x 736 pixels
- Size for iPhone 6 with @2x scaling, Coordinate space: 375 x 667 pixels

Comment: Best approach is to use AutoLayout. http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is already answered  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2hTR.png)

You just need to use new `Xcode 6` Gold master and it will scale your screen for both new sizes.
With that their are several new options in new `Xcode 6` if you creating new application, some of them are given below:

Couple of options to select **splash screen**:
You can now select launch screen file(xib), with that you can also use assets catalog.
[image]

You are looking for specific size for devices you can check that in attribute inspector of assets catalog.

For the rest of the app screens optimization you just need to `Auto layout`.