# iOS - Need to resize a button and image for different iPhones

Tags: ios, iphone, image, image-resizing

I have a really simple App, with one view, one button with one activity when you press this button. The button is full screen size, as well as the image that is in it.

I have it running on my iPhone 6 Plus perfectly, after spending a long time getting the Controller View, View Container, and Button sizes to work together so it is seen properly on the iPhone 6 plus, both hardware and virtual.

The button and image are full screen size, and it took some fenagling to get even this to work for ONE iPhone size. LOL. The Controller View is one size, which is NOT the real life size of my iPhone 6 plus. It is larger. So the View Container is the correct size, along with the button. The image is PNG 401PPI 1080 x 1920 as Apple recommends for the iPhone 6 plus. It looks correct on my iPhone.

My issue is the following: How do I now take my App, and create the other two sizes for the iPhone 5 and iPhone 4?

I have scoured here and on the Apple Developer website to absolutely no avail whatsoever. Nothing I have tried so far, has done anything but make me pull my hair.

I am using XCode 6.4 and targeting iOS 8 and above.

Here is what I have set within the XCode environment:

iPhone 6 plus layout details:

a. View Controller attributes:
- resize view from NIB
- Presentation : Fullscreen
- Simulated metrics iPhone 5.5 inch, fixed size (seems too big, the image is not fullsize to this size) 414 x 736

b. ViewContainer
- Mode: scale to fill (scales to View Controller above)

c. Button
- Image = iOS 401PPI.png
- Alignment = Centered horizontal and vertical
- Edge = Content
- View = Scale to Fill
— Size Inspector
View = Width 375 x Height 652
Intrinsic Size = Default

screen actual size =    667 x 375   “ViewContainer”

button size =           652 x 375   “button”

Image is original 401ppi 1080 x 1920 @ 401 ppi

HELP...

Comment: Sounds to me like you're an Android developer. iPhone uses points and picks the appropriate image based on naming. Non retina iPhone uses image.png and is 320x480 points/pixels but retina phones like iPhone 4 uses image@2x.png naming and the dimension is 320x480 points BUT 480x640 pixels (double the amount of pixels). iPhone 6 and 6+ uses image@3x.png naming.

Comment: You can use autolayout, pl. refer to the below tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/. Also it is been discussed in the below stackoverflow link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780213/handle-ui-in-all-iphones-with-different-scaling-resolutions?rq=1

Comment: Hi Zhang, thank you for the comment, I will try these things next. Yes, I have done a little bit of Android development, for this same App. It seems easier in android, but I also have to have this on iPhones. So, if I am able to create my images, and simply name them as you suggest, would that possibly work? I will try that, and also the links you provided.

Comment: Try taking a 300x300 image call it image@3x.png, then resize that 300x300 image down to 200x200 image, call it image@2x.png and then repeat for 100x100, calling it image.png. When you drag all three image files into the Image.xcassets window in Xcode. Create a UIImageView and set the property myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:"image"]; I also recommend using auto layout but you can also use frames. Try running the app on different simulator, you should see the image stays the same relative size (to the screen) on different device resolution. I'll add demo code below.

Comment: Hi Zhang, this is working well now, thanks!!! I renamed my already resized images to image, image@2x, and image@3x, and created a new image asset with those three, and it is now resizing as it should. Which is pretty much the same as in Android, except for the extra step in creating an asset catalog. Now I'll add my button and continue on.

Comment: The iPhone image sizes is as follows:
image.png = 240 PPI 2048 x 1536
image@2x = 326 PPI 960 x 640
image@3x = 401 PPI 1920 x 1080

Comment: What I don't like in Android is when I create my image assets, I have to save the file with a placeholder suffix so the OS doesn't complain about the same file name being used, then I move the file to the appropriate folder, then I have to delete the extra placeholder suffix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Zhang. 
I went ahead and created a new asset catalog with three images, one for each size of iPhone, and then simply dragged the images into that folder in the XCode editor window.

The contents.json asset catalog file looks like this:

Contents.json :

```
{
  "images" : [
{
  "idiom" : "universal",
  "scale" : "1x",
  "filename" : "MainImage.png"
},
{
  "idiom" : "universal",
  "scale" : "2x",
  "filename" : "MainImage@2x.png"
},
{
  "idiom" : "universal",
  "scale" : "3x",
  "filename" : "MainImage@3x.png"
}
],
"info" : {
"version" : 1,
"author" : "xcode"
}
}
```

With the exception that I am using Swift which makes this less code and therefore simpler, your answer is spot on. In Swift, there is no more need for two files for the ViewController, only one. I also was able to assign my sound to a single button within the ViewController, removing the need for any ImageView container for my background image:

ViewController :

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var myPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

var yourSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("RemSound_01", ofType: "wav")!)
func initYourSound() {
    myPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: yourSound, error: nil)
    myPlayer.prepareToPlay()
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initYourSound()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func playMySound(sender: AnyObject) {
    myPlayer.play()
}
}
```

I hope this helps anyone starting out coding with Swift in XCode.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone and iOS system uses smart naming system to select the appropriate resolution image based on the device the image is being rendered on.

Back then, an iPhone 3 or 3gs has a screen dimension of 320x480 pixels. In this environment, if we wanted a button that is 100 x 50 pixels, then we created one of that size in Photoshop.

With the introduction of the Retina displays, the screen pixel resolution is doubled, but Apple wants to make it easier for the developer so with our Objective C code, we still tell our button to be 100x50 dimension but iOS measures it in points instead of pixels.

That way, on Retina screen, 100x50 points is converted to 200x100 pixels.

iOS will also then try to find an image with a naming suffix "@2x" and load this one if it's available.

### Demo

So suppose we got this public domain eggs image here:

[image: eggs]

http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/view-image.php?image=14453&picture=easter-eggs-in-grass&large=1

Which I've resized to 600x900 for the eggs@3x.png iPhone 6/6+ image.

Then the we have:

- eggs@3x.png 600x900 pixels
- eggs@2x.png 400x600 pixels
- eggs.png 200x300 pixels

Create a new Single View Template project in Xcode. Drag and drop all three eggs images to the `Image.xcassets` file manager. Then modify the ViewController file to look like this:

### ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

### ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self initViews];
    [self initConstraints];
}

-(void)initViews
{
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    // extension not needed since we added images to the
    // Images.xcassets manager instead of directly to project
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eggs"];

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    // image might not cover the imageView's frame, I'm using
    // a grey background color so you can see where the frame is
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    // images may or may not be square, we use AspectFit
    // to ensure we can see the entire image within the
    // dimension we specified without any cropping
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;




    // add the view to the view controller's view
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageView];
}

-(void)initConstraints
{
    // tell iOS we want to use Autolayout for our imageView
    self.imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    // ---------------------------------------------
    // name binding for our imageView for
    // Autolayout Visual Formatting Language
    // ---------------------------------------------
    NSMutableDictionary *viewNames = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [viewNames setValue:self.imageView forKey:@"imageView"];



    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Autolayout code
    //
    // H: for horizontal constraint
    // V: for vertical constraint
    // |: parent view edges (so H:| == left edge for example)
    //
    //
    // Here we're telling our imageView to be offset 50 pixels
    // from the left and right as well as 50 pixels from the top
    // and bottom of its parent view, which in this case, is our
    // View Controller's view
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-50-[imageView]-50-|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                        views:viewNames]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-50-[imageView]-50-|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:viewNames]];

}
```

Unfortunately, Xcode no longer comes with iPhone 3/3gs simulator, only retina iPhones.

### iPhone 4/4s simulator result

[image]

### iPhone 5/5s simulator result

[image]

### iPhone 6 simulator result

[image]

Notice how our imageView's frame remains 50 pixels offset on all four sides, relative to the view controller's view ?

If you want the image to fill the entire ImageView's frame, you can use the `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` instead of `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` in the above code.

This yields a result like this:

[image]

So in the case of your button image, you would do something similar.

Comment: Thank you Zhang. WIth the exception that I am using Swift which makes this less code and therefore simpler, your answer is spot on.